# Return Null in select box for choose city and state

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, sql-update, migration, database-migration

This is my 2 models. I Add migration and update it successfully.

```
  public class UserInfo : BaseEntity
{
    #region FirstSartProgram

    public long UserPackageId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [MaxLength(350)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Job")]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Job { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UserInfoSituation")]
    public UserInfoSituation? UserInfoSituation { get; set; }

    .....


     public long? LocationId { get; set; }

#region Relations

    public ICollection<PackageFile> PackageFiles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserPackageId")]
    public UserPackage UserPackage { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location.Location Location { get; set; }

    #endregion
```

and second one is:

```
   #region Properties

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public long? ParentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IsDeleted")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Relations

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Location Parent { get; set; }

 
    public ICollection<UserInfo.UserInfo>  UserInfos { get; set; }

    #endregion
```

---

As I said update database is ok.
I write some method for create a form.but when I want create or edit for with this method I have error:

```
    [HttpPost("userInfo/first-start-userInfo/{packageId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FirstStartUserInfo(CreateFirstStartUserInfoViewModel firstStartUserInfo)
    {
        var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(firstStartUserInfo);
        var res = await _packageService.CreateFirstStartUserInfoByUser(firstStartUserInfo, userId);
        switch (res.UserInfoType)
        {
            case UserInfoType.NotValid: return RedirectToAction("NotFound","Home");
            case UserInfoType.NotFound: return RedirectToAction("NotFound","Home");
            case UserInfoType.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("SecondStartUserInfo", "UserInfo", new { UserInfoId = res.UserInfoId,menu=UserPanelMenu.Packages });
        }
        return View(firstStartUserInfo);
    }
```

I see city and state in select list .
but when I create form, Location Id is null on database

view:

```
 <form method="post" asp-controller="UserInfo" asp-action="FirstStartUserInfo" asp-route-menu="Packages">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="PackageId" />
            <div>
                <div class="col-xl-7">
                    
                    
                    <div class="my-4">
                        <label class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center" for="">
                            <label>State </label>
                          
                            <select   asp-for="LocationId" asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["State"]"  class="form-control">
                               
                            </select>
                            <label>city </label>
                            <select  asp-for="LocationId" asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["City"]" id=" " class="form-control ">
                              
                            </select>
                        </label>
                     
                    </div>
```

........

```
 @{
ViewData["Title"] = _localizer["GetUserInfo"];
IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> state = ViewData["State"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;   
IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> city = ViewData["City"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;
```

}

Comment: Hi @hasti.au, Did the `FirstStartUserInfo` method used to render your view? If so, please set breakpoint and check if `firstStartUserInfo`  variable have `LocationId` in your method.  And what is your `CreateFirstStartUserInfoViewModel`? Many things you do not tell us. Please share more details.

Answer (score 0):

`LocationId` is null because you did not pass this from selectlist Id `@ViewData["State","YouStateId"]`.

try this:-

```
<select   asp-for="LocationId" asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["State","YouStateId"]"  class="form-control">
```

Here you pass `StateId` using selectlist. when you create, then you will find  `LocationId` with your state/city.

**You actually not posted your model clearly. I assume your model design is ok and you have a primary key for all your model. also have a separate ForeignKey for city and state in a model as needed.**

Comment: on get method I show all state and city. but when I want to use post method, location Id does not pass . l can pass to view model all parameter except location Id. location is another model(table) .I want to get from location model to this user info view model

Comment: I set it on view data .I update m answer. how can I pass location Id from another model(table) to this view Model?

Comment: @hasti.au I see your model where you used ``` locationId``` as a foreignkey.also, it's nullable.but I don't see your primary key in this model.use primary key and foreign key separately and obviously, you did not post clearly your class model and these name.for that I am confused.

Comment: @hasti.au If you want I will connect your computer via TeamViewer and try. I see your posted question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516712/pass-id-from-one-model-to-another-model-with-view-models-in-net-core  i think it's still not cleare.

Comment: yes here I post cleared my 2 models and 2 view models . now I want to know how can get location Id in "Location" table at the other view model(or model)? should I  use include?

Comment: @hasti.au I want to connect your computer via TeamViewer and gonna the last try. did you use TeamViewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235270/discussion-between-pritom-sarkar-and-hasti-au).