# Pass Id From One Model to Another Model (with View Models) In .NET Core

Tags: database, asp.net-core, controller, return, return-value

I have 2 models and their view models:

```
public class Location:BaseEntity
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public long? ParentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IsDeleted")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Location Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserInfo.UserInfo>  UserInfos { get; set; }
}
```

And this is its view model:

```
public class UserLocationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public long LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

The second one is this, and its view model has "Location Id":

```
public class UserInfo : BaseEntity
{
    public long UserPackageId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [MaxLength(350)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PackageFile> PackageFiles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserPackageId")]
    public UserPackage UserPackage { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location.Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

I have some method .there are 2 table. but I want to create a form with 2 view model. how can I pass LocationId from table "Location" to another model "UserInfo"

This is my service:

```
public async Task<(UserInfoType UserInfoType, long UserInfoId)> CreateFirstStartUserInfoByUser(CreateFirstStartUserInfoViewModel firstStartUserInfo, long userId)
{
    if (!await IsPackagePurchasedByUser(userId, firstStartUserInfo.PackageId)) 
        return (UserInfoType.NotFound, 0);

    var userPackageId = await _packageRepository.GetUserPackageIdByUserIdAndPackageId(userId, firstStartUserInfo.PackageId);

    if (userPackageId <= 0) 
        return (UserInfoType.NotValid, 0);
      
    if (await _packageRepository.IsExistUserInfoByUserPackageId(userPackageId))
    {
        long userInfoId = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            EditFirstStartUserInfoViewModel editFirstStartUserInfo = new EditFirstStartUserInfoViewModel()
                {
                    PackageId = firstStartUserInfo.PackageId,
                    Address = firstStartUserInfo.Address,
                    DayOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.DayOfBirth,
                    Goal = firstStartUserInfo.Goal,
                    Job = firstStartUserInfo.Job,
                    Marriage = firstStartUserInfo.Marriage,
                    MonthOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.MonthOfBirth,
                    Sex = firstStartUserInfo.Sex,
                    UserPackageId = userPackageId,
                    UserInfoId = await _packageRepository.GetUserInfoIdByUserPackageIdAndUserInfoSituation(userPackageId, i),
                    YearOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.YearOfBirth,
                    
                    LocationId = await GetUserLocationIdForCreate(firstStartUserInfo)
                };

            await EditFirstStartUserInfoByUser(editFirstStartUserInfo, userId);

            if (i == 1) 
                userInfoId = editFirstStartUserInfo.UserInfoId;
        }

        if (userInfoId <= 0) 
            return (UserInfoType.NotValid, 0);

        return (UserInfoType.Success, userInfoId);
    }

    // this id is userInfo id
    long id = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        UserInfo UserInfo = new UserInfo()
            {
                UserPackageId = userPackageId,
                Address = firstStartUserInfo.Address.SanitizeText(),
                Job = firstStartUserInfo.Job.SanitizeText(),
                DayOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.DayOfBirth,
                MonthOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.MonthOfBirth,
                YearOfBirth = firstStartUserInfo.YearOfBirth,
                Sex = firstStartUserInfo.Sex,
                Marriage = firstStartUserInfo.Marriage,
                Goal = firstStartUserInfo.Goal.SanitizeText(),
                UserInfoSituation = (UserInfoSituation?)i,
                EditExpireDate = null,
                LocationId =????????
            };

        await _packageRepository.CreateUserInfo(UserInfo);
        await _packageRepository.SaveChanges();

        if (i == 1) 
            id = UserInfo.Id;
    }

    if (id <= 0) 
        return (UserInfoType.NotValid, 0);

    return (UserInfoType.Success, id);
}
```

This is my controller on post method:

```
      var state = await _packageService.GetStateForUserInfo();
        ViewData["State"] = state;


        var firstLocationId = state.FirstOrDefault().LocationId;
        var city = await _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(firstLocationId);
        ViewData["City"] = city;
```

Comment: Please provide more code, at least I think the UserLocationViewModel class is missing something.

Comment: It has just title and location Id .Because I have just one table for state and city, I pass it with view data on controller but because of use FirstOrDefualt ,it saves just 1st record of table. I update my question